# Convert list to a string in Oz?

Tags: oz

How to convert a list to a string in [Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_%28programming_language%29)?

I have a list of characters I need to convert to a string and I didn't see any concatenation operator in the Oz documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A list of characters *is* a string in oz. `[102 111 111]` is the same as `"foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

To see the string in the browser and not the list, open the browser with a `Browse` and choose *Options/Representations* and enable *Strings*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because a string is a list of characters. However, 'hello' is not a string in oz, but "hello" is.